async/await is not yet supported in Client Components in dApp with nextjs
I am attempting to create an app which needs to interact with smart contracts, and when attempting to supply a provider for web3.eth.Contract I get the error async/await is not yet supported in Client Components
I am also confused as to whether a provider is needed for web3.eth.Contract.
'use client'

declare let window: any;
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import Web3 from "web3";
import MarketABI from '../abi/Market.json';
import TokenABI from '../abi/Token.json';
import { usePrivy } from "@privy-io/react-auth";

interface DataContextProps {
  loading: boolean;
  account: string;
  loadAuth: () => Promise<void>;
  loadBlockchainData: () => Promise<void>;
  market: any;
  token: any;
};

const DataContext = createContext<DataContextProps>({
  loading: true,
  account: "",
  loadAuth: async () => {},
  loadBlockchainData: async () => {},
  market: null,
  token: null,
});

interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const DataProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const data = useProviderData();

  return <DataContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>;
};

export const useData = () => useContext<DataContextProps>(DataContext);

export const useProviderData = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
  const [market, setMarket] = useState<any>();
  const [token, setToken] = useState<any>();
  const {wallets} = useWallets();
  const {ready, authenticated, user} = usePrivy();

  const loadAuth = async () => {
    if (ready && authenticated && user) {
      const userWallet = user.wallet ? user.wallet.address : "";
      setAccount(userWallet);
    }
  };

  const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
    const wallet = wallets[0];
    await wallet.switchChain(sepolia.id);
    const provider = await wallet.getEthereumProvider();
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    
    var tempContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
      MarketABI,
      '0xD72C08f47188a41E9182F793ed6d46192db61D9A'
    );
    setMarket(tempContract);

    var tempTokenContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
      TokenABI,
      '0x45f2A40B3CfFC1547fc90e8A65786E7E2fF99458'
    );
    setToken(tempTokenContract);
       
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 500);
  };

  return {
    account,
    market,
    token,
    loading,
    loadAuth,
    loadBlockchainData,
  };
};


The loadBlockchainData() is then used in page.tsx inside app folder.
'use client'

import Head from "next/head";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Navbar = dynamic(() => import("../components/Navbar"), {
  ssr: false,
});
import { useData } from "../contexts/DataContext";

export interface MarketProps {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
export default function Home() {
const { market, account, loadAuth, loadBlockchainData, loading } = useData();
const [markets, setMarkets] = useState<MarketProps[]>([]);

const getMarkets = useCallback(async () => {
  var totalMarkets = await market.methods
    .totalMarkets()
    .call({ from: account });

  var dataArray: MarketProps[] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < totalMarkets; i++) {
    var data = await market.methods.markets(i).call({ from: account });
    dataArray.push({
      id: data.id,
      title: data.market,
    });
  }
  setMarkets(dataArray);
}, [account, market]);

useEffect(() => {
  loadBlockchainData().then(() => {
    if (!loading) getMarkets();
  });
}, [loading, account]);

return // Html content

}

Also, what is the purpose of .call({ from: account })?

Are you using 'use client' anywhere in the page component? Or are you using 'use client' for a component that uses await in the component's block scope?

The .call method allows you to change who this refers to inside the function. Most likely, the market.methods.markets(i) function references this inside of it, and it order to tell it who this is you use the .call method.

Yes I am using use client in the context and page files.

Your code example does not display any of that so it's a bit hard to suggest what you should do. Though it's best to avoid having 'use client' inside a page component, so maybe just extract the logic into another component and pass the result of that async function as props. That way your page can remain a server component (so you can use async/await in it).

I have updated the question with the full code for both files. I have attempted to extract loadBlockchainData() logic to a different file but to no avail since I am still importing it to a client component. How would you suggest to restructure it, please share your solution?

@moonstar-x that call is different in the context of ethereum my friend

My bad, I got tunnel vision when I saw the call method and automatically assumed it was the Function.prototype.call one.
